# integral inequality proof

Tags: calculus, integration

How should I prove this inequality for $x>5$?

$$3(x-5) +\dfrac{9}{x}-\dfrac{9}{5}<\int_{5}^{x}\dfrac{3t^2}{t^2+3}dt<3(x-5)$$

I believe taking the derivative would be a good place to start but in order for that inequality to hold I would first have to show that $f(a)<g(a)<h(a)$ for $a>5$.  I became stuck when trying this first step.  I tried plugging in $x=5+h$ to see if I could first prove the inequality at a point first but I didn't seem to get anywhere doing that.  Is this a suitable approach?  If it is, should I be using something other than $x=5+h$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does $h$ stand for?

Comment: Hint: try to write the upper and lower bounds in an integral form.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson I guess it is a typo and should be $3(x-5)$

Comment: Ahh!  Sorry for the typo

Comment: Careful - definite integration preserves inequalities, but differentiation does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**hint**

Let $x>5$. For $t\in [5,x] $, we have

$$f (t)=\frac {3t^2}{t^2+3}=\frac {3t^2+9-9}{t^2+3} $$
$$=3-\frac {9}{t^2+3} $$

$$\implies 3-\frac {9}{t^2} <f (t)< 3$$

$$\implies $$
$$\int_5^x (3-\frac {9}{t^2})dt< \int_5^xf (t)dt<3\int_5^x dt $$
You are Done.